# Orchard implementation No persister for "table Name"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orchardcms

Error occurs when i am trying to save data.
error is:
No persister for:  "test.FileRecord"(Table name what i have created and want to insert data into this table)

Comment: Can you post the code that is giving the error? Is this "FileRecord" the underlying record for a Content Part, or just a standalone record?

Answer (score 0):

Orchard uses specific naming convention (`[ModuleName]_FileRecord`) for tables and requires to stick to it if you want to have table records automatically mapped to objects. `[ModuleName]` is the name of your module with dots (.) replaced with underscores (_).

I assume you have a `FileRecord` object, that you want to use through `IRepository<FileRecord>`, right? *This is the correct way of working with database in Orchard, btw.* If your module is called `My.Module`, then the table name should be `My_Module_FileRecord`.

If you have everything set up as described above then it should be working fine.

Comment: I am also facing the same error. My fully qualified name of the class matches with that of tablename (with . replaced by _). Note I am persisting non-content items. Any tips on how could I debug the NHibernate "No Perister" error? Anyway I can specify mapping between class and table manually ?